# ErrorListPlot crops error bars

Tags: plotting

The default behaviour of `ErrorListPlot` often crops error bars, as in the example below. How can this be fixed in a clean way?

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
data = Table[{{x, Cos[x]}, ErrorBar[Cos[x]^2]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
plot = ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image: The ErrorListPlot generated by the above code]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just `Show` `plot` with the option `PlotRange -> All`:

```
Show[plot, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Why?

`plot` already  contains full lines which you can see by looking at `plot[[1]]` which contains all the graphics directives and primitives:

```
Graphics[plot[[1]]]
```

[image]

Somehow, the `FrontEnd` *thinks* displaying the cropped version is in some sense *better*. You can always override the rendering choices of the `FrontEnd` using `Show` with appropriate options.

Comment: Much neater! I feel like a right mug now

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution. Calculate the value of each data point plus (and minus) it's error bar. Then you can calculate the location of the highest (and lowest) error bar. Then use this to specify the `PlotRange`.

```
data = Table[{{x, Cos[x]}, ErrorBar[Cos[x]^2]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
minima = #[[1]][[2]] - #[[2]][[1]] & /@ data;
maxima = #[[1]][[2]] + #[[2]][[1]] & /@ data;
plot = ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {Min[minima], Max[maxima]}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image: ErrorListPlot generated by the above code]

We can make a nice little function that we can use in a similar way to `ErrorListPlot` but takes care of the `PlotRange` automatically as we desired. The difference here is that other optional arguments have to be grouped together into a list. I'm sure there's a nicer way to do this with optional arguments, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
errorListPlot[data_, opts_] := Module[{minima, maxima},
  minima = #[[1]][[2]] - #[[2]][[1]] & /@ data;
  maxima = #[[1]][[2]] + #[[2]][[1]] & /@ data;
  ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {Min[minima], Max[maxima]}, opts]
  ]

data = Table[{{x, Cos[x]}, ErrorBar[Cos[x]^2]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
errorListPlot[data, {PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], PlotStyle -> Red}]
```

[image: ErrorListPlot generated with custom 'errorListPlot' Module defined above]