# Define function that behaves almost identically to Mathematica function

Tags: functions, optional-arguments, arguments

Often I like to define my own functions that are almost exactly the same as Mathematica defined functions, apart from a few tweaks. See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191880/errorlistplot-crops-error-bars/191881#191881) for example. I want to define them properly so they handle optional arguments correctly. What is a general strategy for accomplishing this? Here's a concrete (esoteric) example. I define `myListPlot` that is almost identical to `ListPlot` except that is adds a gridline corresponding to the first data point.

```
data = Table[RandomReal[], {x, 1, 10}]
myListPlot[data_, opts_] := ListPlot[data, GridLines -> {None, {data[[1]]}}, opts]
myListPlot[data, {PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True}]
```

[image: The ListPlot generated by the above code]

Not too bad. However I have to pass the optional arguments as a list. Instead, I would like to pass the optional arguments in the same way one does with `ListPlot`. In other words, I would like to modify `myListPlot` so that I would pass arguments like

```
myListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True]
```

Perhaps I'm going about this completely the wrong way. Nevertheless I hope the reader understands what I'm trying to accomplish and can suggest a solution.

Comment: Try changing `myListPlot[data_, opts_]` to `myListPlot[data_, opts___]`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Why not go ahead and make it an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to constrain it to only options from [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html), you could use [`OptionsPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionsPattern.html) in combination with [`FilterRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilterRules.html)and [`Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html).

```
myListPlot[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ListPlot[data, GridLines -> {None, {data[[1]]}}, 
  FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListPlot]]]
```

which  results in:

```
myListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `OptionsPattern[ListPlot]` is more precise.

Answer (score 9):

The usual way to define a Wolfram Language function that takes `n` arguments and an arbitrary number of options is like this:

```
f[arg1_, ..., argn_, opts___] := ...
```

A little bit of pattern matching background (taken from [the WL reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsWithVariableNumbersOfArguments.html)):

- `_`   any single expression
- `x_`  any single expression, to be named `x`
- `__`  any sequence of one or more expressions
- `x__` sequence named `x`
- `x__h`    sequence of expressions, all of whose heads are `h`
- `___` any sequence of zero or more expressions
- `x___`    sequence of zero or more expressions named `x`
- `x___h`   sequence of zero or more expressions, all of whose heads are `h`