# Modified BoxWhiskerChart for statistical summary of data

Tags: plotting, charts

I would like to make a statistical graph (chart) from data in the format {x-value, mean value, standard deviation} as in:

{{10, 10.73, 0.72}, 
 {20, 14.10, 0.49}, 
 {30, 13.96, 0.49}, 
 {40, 13.43, 0.51}}

I would like the graph to resemble a `BoxWhiskerChart`, where at each x value the mean is plotted and thin bars extending above and below the mean by a distance equal to the standard deviation.  However, `BoxWhiskerChart` requires the data at each x value to be an entire data *set* (of multiple points), not the statistical summary.  I have merely the mean and standard deviation.

I can kludge drawing lines by computing ranges and such, as follows:

```
Show[ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]],
  Joined -> True,
  PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}],
 Epilog -> 
  Table[{Red, 
    Line[{{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]] - data[[i, 3]]}, {data[[i, 1]], 
       data[[i, 2]] + data[[i, 3]]}}]}, {i, Length[data]}]]
```

[image]

However, because I have lots of data, and ultimately wish to place several such plots on a single graph (of different colors), I was hoping there was a way to modify `BoxWhiskerChart` (or related chart) so I can exploit the internal functions and styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {{10, 10.73, 0.72}, {20, 14.10, 0.49}, {30, 13.96, 0.49}, {40, 13.43, 0.51}};

ListLinePlot[ {#1, Around[#2, #3]} & @@@ list ]
```

[image: plot with error bars]

---

For previous versions (`Around` is new in 12.0):

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
Show[ErrorListPlot[list], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: errorlistplot]

`ErrorListPlot` takes the option `Joined -> True`, just like `ListPlot`, if you want the connecting lines as well. The weird `Show[.., PlotRange -> All]` is there to avoid [clipping of the error bars](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/191880/27951).

Comment: Wow... I had never seen that function.  Thanks so much!  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think it's new in 12.0. Pretty handy, finally there is a simple a way of generating plots with proper error bar in MMA :-)

Comment: Ugh... I "accepted" too soon.  I am running v. 11.3 and it doesn't work.  Any suggestion for v. 11.3?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yep, see edit.

Comment: Got it.  Works.  Thanks so much.  (Previous acceptance now fully justified!)